# Scald : How to add several medias to a node using entity metadata wrapper?

Tags: entities, media, scald

I'm looking for a solution to my problem that is pretty simple in fact. 
I'm on an importing task in which I have to create programmatically a node and then populate all its fields.

As we're using the [Scald](https://www.drupal.org/project/scald) module, we can add several medias to a node. But I can't figure out how to associate several medias to a node ?

I tried the following :

```
foreach ($file_atoms as $i => $atom) {
    $node_wrapper->field_atom[$i] = $atom->sid;
}
```

or :

```
foreach ($file_atoms as $i => $atom) {
    $node_wrapper->field_atom[$i]->set($atom->sid);
}
```

But I get the following error :

> Error: Cannot use object of type EntityDrupalWrapper as array

I followed the doc on [this page](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers) but it does not seems to work..

Can somebody help me ?

I'm encountering the same problem with taxonomies : I'm not able to set multiple values to the node wrapper.

Comment: Are you sure the `field_atom` field has the option of taking multiple medias?

Comment: Good question, the field is not configured for several medias... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that your `field_atom` field is not configured as multiple.

When it's not, an `EntityDrupalWrapper` object will give you direct access to the field, instead of having to go through the `0` delta.

Just fix the `field_atom` options to accept multiple medias, and your code will work fine.